# sql query get next free id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an brain hitch and don't find the right solution for my query. May be some one has an idea?

I want to find the next free no with following where clause:

My curent SQL Code is:

```
SELECT min(`no` + 1) AS nextNo 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE `no` + 1 not in (
  SELECT `no` 
  FROM `table1` 
  WHERE `sno` = 20 
)
```

This are my table values:

```
id=1, no=1, sno=20
```

If `sno=20` then my result for `nextNo=2` and that is correct.

But if I use `sno=10`, my result for `**nextNo**=2` and not `1`

*Many many thanks for help!*

Comment: Please provide more sample data and results.  I don't know what "next free no" means.

Comment: For your specific problem, `select min` should be `select max`.

Comment: This type of ID generation is prone to race conditions which may result in the same ID being selected twice and thus the same NextNo could be issued.  Using a system generated ID takes care of this, or you have to build your own locking method to ensure the ID you get isn't issued to somone else before the insert.

Comment: For example, between NO 1 to 6 the 4 is missing.

If I search for SNO 1, the result for nextNo is 4, that's right.

But if I search for SNO 2, the result for nextNo should be 1, but my code result 2

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you just go for one more than the maximum for a given `sno`:

```
select coalesce(max(no) + 1, 1)
from table1 t1
where sno = 20;
```

If you really want to fill holes (which generally doesn't seem like a good idea):

```
select coalesce(min(t1.no) + 1, 1)
from table1 t1
where t1.sno = 20 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.sno = t1.sno and tt1.no = t1.no + 1
                 );
```

Comment: Your second query is the right way, but i get an SQL syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1))

Comment: No where in the 2nd query does it show a 1 with )) after it.  Are you sure your attempt matches this?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is confusing ,Please give us more details. If you want to find next number which is not available in table1 , you may use

```
SELECT max(`no`) + 1 AS nextNo FROM `table1`
```

And your query return 2 for sno=10 because, your where condition is ambiguous and true for all the values.

Comment: I understand, do you have any idea to solve the ambiguous condition?

Comment: Where condition in your query seems useless. I would prefer to use the first query by @gorden